# AWS EC2 what happens with files when server crashes or interrupts

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, server, rstudio-server

I have an Rscript running on an AWS EC2 instance. Also, I set up a crontab, which triggers the Rscript to run every 5 minutes. 
My script will read out data from a website and append a new line to an existing CSV file.
My Rscript is located at

```
/home/rstudio/Rscript.R
```

and the csv-file is located in the same "rstudio" folder. I am new to AWS and want to know, how secure this is, e.g. when the server will crash or be interrupted? Would it be better to store it in an S3 instance?

Another question would be, what is the recommended way to finally download the CSV-file to my local computer?

Answer (score 0):

Files stored on EBS won't be affected, files stored on instance storage will be gone.

So any disks you linked to the server during the instance creation will be persistent and (mostly) safe from crashes. The only thing that can happen is the disk becoming unbootable because the OS corrupt something, but then you should still be able to mount it on another instance and get the data that way.